# How to find channels with youtube API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, similarity

As you all know when using youtube api to search for a channel you don't really get the right term. As for example, when searching for 'netfactor' channel it doesn't return me anything because the channel name is 'netFactor'. So how i can implement a method to try to search for all the similarities of a word or to make my method to return all the channels found.

```
def YoutubeSearch():
    API_KEY = os.environ["API_KEY"]
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey= 'API_KEY')
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part = "snippet",
        forUsername = 'netfactor'
    )
    response = request.execute()
    if response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] > 0 :
        print(response)
```

Comment: You are looking for [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint.

Comment: Now i figured out. This youtube API documentation isn't so clear as i expected. Thanks! :)