# How to return YouTube channel information based on a unique channel name or ID

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am trying to do a simply Python script that returns some information about a channel via `@username` or `UCrandomID123` search.

I know that you can use the following endpoint to access channel data: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels

However, I came across some possible restrictions and problems. Some channels might not have their custom "name" in their channel URL:

[image]

vs.

[image]

I looked up the problem and came across multiple posts addressing the issue:

- [How to find channels with youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582656/how-to-find-channels-with-youtube-api)
- [Find YouTube user name for a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67508794/find-youtube-user-name-for-a-channel)

But both of the solutions are rather old, and I was wondering if there's now a better solution to this issue?

**I have the following code:**

```py
async def get_channel_id(self, channel_input):
        api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
        params = {
            'part': 'snippet',
            'key': DEVELOPER_KEY,
            'maxResults': 1
        }

        # Determine if the input is a channel ID or username
        if channel_input.startswith('UC'):
            # Channel ID provided
            params['id'] = channel_input
        else:
            # Assume it's a custom username
            params['forUsername'] = channel_input

        response = await self.make_api_request(api_url, params) # Just a function to make an async req.
        if response and response.get('items'):
            channel_info = response['items'][0]
            channel_id = channel_info['id']
            channel_title = channel_info['snippet']['title']
            channel_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}"
            return channel_id, channel_title, channel_url
        return None, None, None
```

This one works fine if I have the `UC....` URL but giving the unique "username", it fails to find the channel for some reason. The reason I want to catch both cases is that right now, the majority of channels has such a custom name URL.

Comment: Have a look to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Thanks for the suggestion. I am not really willing to host any API myself or rely on a service that may end its service after some time. I am rather looking for a code-based solution or a package that I can integrate into my code to fix the issue.

Comment: Will you accept a yt-dlp solution?

Comment: @qwr Depends. If it's breaking after some time, because of missing updates to the package, it's not really what I am looking for. The package looks to be active, but we all know the history of such... More than happy to get the input anyway!

Comment: *we all know the history of such* may you elaborate what you mean? As YouTube UI sometimes change, hence even with a very up-to-date package you will have to update it sometimes to not have your workflow broken.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Some other packages died rather quick as it's pretty hard to maintain them. If one feels comfortable about their package, feel free to share a working solution.

Comment: I am thinking about [implementing a universal library](https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/Webscrap_any_website/issues/12) to replace [my current open-source YouTube-operational-API PHP HTTPS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723131/how-to-return-youtube-channel-information-based-on-a-unique-channel-name-or-id#comment137022537_77723131) but it will not be available in the next days. You can `Subscribe` to `Notifications` of this Git issue to stay tuned about its progress.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly is failing? It seems a bit ambiguous. Your current implementation should theoretically work just fine as per Google's API reference. I tried simple cURL, and it does work.
`GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&maxResults=1&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1`

and
`GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=GoogleDevelopers&maxResults=1&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1`

Both work just fine.

Comment: @zettachad It simply fails for some channels. Just ran a check again and my code works for `PewDiePie`  or `tseries` but not for channels like `maxxpane` (1.3 mio. subscribers)

Comment: Dominik, how about if you just pull the html of the page that uses the username and then just parse it to get the channel id.  Every page I have looked up by username has the channel id in a link in the source.  I could give you some python code to pull the channel id from the source if that is an acceptable solution for you.

Comment: @JosephIshak I don't quite know if that's what I am looking for... I want to either give the username or the `UC` name and still get the exact channel in both cases to work with them. It should be somewhat an API solution or with a different package I can install.

Comment: I was more thinking of the lines of just converting all usernames to the UC name which seems to always work and then only making api calls using the UC name rather than dealing with the shortcomings of an api that isn't working properly or consistently with the username.  I will share my answer below.

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a solution modifying the query params

Hope this works for you

```
import requests

# Replace with your own Google API key
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'your_api_key_here'

def get_channel_id(channel_input):
    api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
        'key': DEVELOPER_KEY
    }

    # Determine if the input is a channel ID or username
    if channel_input.startswith('@'):
        # Username provided
        params['type'] = 'channel'
        params['q'] = channel_input
    elif channel_input.startswith('UC'):
        # Channel ID provided
        params['id'] = channel_input
        params['maxResults'] = 1
    else:
        print("Invalid input format. Please provide a valid YouTube username (starting with '@') or channel ID (starting with 'UC').")
        return None, None, None

    response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if 'items' in data and data['items']:
            channel_info = data['items'][0]['snippet']
            channel_id = channel_info['channelId']
            channel_title = channel_info['title']
            channel_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}"
            return channel_id, channel_title, channel_url
        else:
            print("No channels found in the response.")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

    return None, None, None

# Replace 'your_channel_input_here' with the YouTube username or channel ID you want to search for
channel_input_to_search = 'UC or @Username'

# Run the search
result = get_channel_id(channel_input_to_search)
print(result)
```

Comment: The problem with the `search` endpoint is that it is heavily using the API points/quota, with up to/more than `100` points per request. As mentioned in my comment to the other answer: I've got a working solution with a `channel` and `search` mix myself, but it's just not convenient enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to the following to pull the source of any page that uses a username and parse the source to get the UC name instead.  This is a rudimentary example with a hardcoded username but should give you a general idea.

```
import requests
import re

#Get the html of a page that uses a username instead of a channel id
response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/@archangelmichaeloc');
s = response.content;

#Write the html to a file
with open("/tmp/test.html", 'ab') as out:
  out.write(s);

#Parse all the urls in the file and put them in a list
with open("/tmp/test.html", 'r') as f:
  urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', f.read());

#Only return entries in the list with channel/UC in them.
matching = [s for s in urls if "channel/UC" in s]

#Remove duplicate entries
matching = list(dict.fromkeys(matching))

#Remove entries that have a question mark with some parameters
matching = [s for s in matching if not "?" in s]

#Remove the mobile site
matching = [s for s in matching if not "m." in s]

#Convert the match to a string
match=matching[0]

#Remove everythiing fom the url except for the channel id
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
split_url = urlsplit(match)
path_array = split_url.path.split('/')

#UCK9elpywnemVLGRTmqDYhiA
print(path_array[2])
```

The print command at the end then gives you a UC name such as `UCK9elpywnemVLGRTmqDYhiA`

Comment: So basically the suggestion here is to keep the request and if it fails the `UC` check, I could try to implement something similar to your code? I am just trying to think out loud here how this could benefit me trying to use the API and something different, as it's not always reliable, at the same time.

Comment: Yes.  The QA Engineer in me says to make your requests as robust as possible.  I know it may not be what you want and possibly may be fragile, but it gives you something that works until either the api gets fixed or you find a more robust solution.  Sometime people need something that just gets them moving when they are blocked.  It sounds like you have the time to wait for something better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some updates: Fallback Mechanism: If the initial attempt with forUsername fails, the script falls back to a search query. This increases the likelihood of finding the channel even if it doesn't have a username set.

```
import requests
import logging

class YouTubeDataAPI:
    def __init__(self, developer_key):
        self.developer_key = developer_key

    async def make_api_request(self, url, params):
        # Add your async HTTP request logic here
        # For example, using aiohttp:
        # async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        #     async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        #         return await response.json()
        pass

    async def get_channel_id(self, channel_input):
        api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
        params = {
            'part': 'snippet',
            'key': self.developer_key,
            'maxResults': 1
        }

        if channel_input.startswith('UC'):
            params['id'] = channel_input
        else:
            params['forUsername'] = channel_input

        response = await self.make_api_request(api_url, params)

        if response and response.get('items'):
            return self.extract_channel_info(response['items'][0])
        else:
            # Fallback to search endpoint if 'forUsername' fails
            return await self.fallback_search(channel_input)

    async def fallback_search(self, username):
        search_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
        params = {
            'part': 'snippet',
            'key': self.developer_key,
            'q': username,
            'type': 'channel',
            'maxResults': 1
        }

        response = await self.make_api_request(search_url, params)
        if response and response.get('items'):
            channel_id = response['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
            return await self.get_channel_id(channel_id)

        logging.error("YouTube channel not found for username: %s", username)
        return None, None, None

    def extract_channel_info(self, channel_data):
        channel_id = channel_data['id']
        channel_title = channel_data['snippet']['title']
        channel_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}"
        return channel_id, channel_title, channel_url

# Example Usage
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
yt_api = YouTubeDataAPI(DEVELOPER_KEY)
channel_info = await yt_api.get_channel_id('CHANNEL_INPUT_HERE')  # Replace 'CHANNEL_INPUT_HERE' with the actual channel ID or username
print(channel_info)
```

Answer (score -1):

Mixed Approach: To cover both cases, you can implement a mixed approach where you first try to query the channel using the 'forUsername' parameter. If the response is empty or there is an error, you can then try querying the channel using the 'id' parameter (assuming the input is a channel ID).

Here's an updated version of your code with this mixed approach:

```
async def get_channel_info(self, channel_input):
    api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
    params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
        'key': DEVELOPER_KEY,
        'maxResults': 1
    }

    # First, try to query by username
    username_attempt = channel_input.startswith('UC')
    if username_attempt:
        params['forUsername'] = channel_input
    else:
        params['id'] = channel_input

    response = await self.make_api_request(api_url, params)

    if response and response.get('items'):
        channel_info = response['items'][0]
        channel_id = channel_info['id']
        channel_title = channel_info['snippet']['title']
        channel_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}"
        return channel_id, channel_title, channel_url

    # If the first attempt failed, try the alternative approach
    if username_attempt:
        params.pop('forUsername')
        params['id'] = channel_input
        response = await self.make_api_request(api_url, params)

        if response and response.get('items'):
            channel_info = response['items'][0]
            channel_id = channel_info['id']
            channel_title = channel_info['snippet']['title']
            channel_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}"
            return channel_id, channel_title, channel_url

    return None, None, None
```

Comment: I already got that in my code as well, in some way. Here, unfortunately, the code always gives out the error on username inputs.